# Table row transitions on android using material design

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout, material-design

Is there a possibility that table rows in a `TableLayout` in android would make some transitions effects? I'm trying to implement material design on my app. Let's say there are 5 rows and what I want is they would start appearing one by one from the bottom of the activity going up to where they should be placed. Is it possible? Any help will be much appreciated :)